# Draw on different side of a cube

Tags: 3d, java-3d

I draw a `colorcube` on the scene.

I want to draw an image on front it and another image on right side of it.

i know must load a image with `textureloader` and add it to a `texture`

and put texture on cube.but i didn't know how put it on right side of it.

Answer (score 1):

The ColorCube class is an 'All In One' class mainly for quick test purpose. If you want create a cube with particular behavior, texture, color, etc. then it's better to create one from scratch.

Check those links (in french but you can read the code) :
http://deven3d.free.fr/java3d/chap03.htm#formesbase 
http://deven3d.free.fr/telechargements/fichiers/java3d/chap03/Box3D/Box3D.java
http://deven3d.free.fr/telechargements/fichiers/java3d/chap03/QuadArray3D/QuadArray3D.java